# Selecting Multiple Classes from an ID selection

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the following XML

```
<div id="Master25" class="open-pane" role="tabpanel">
<a href="/option1" title="option1" class="top-element ">
    <div class="top-element-description">
        <div class="top-element-option-title">Spain</div>
        <div class="top-element-option-description">Test1</div>
    </div>
        <span class="top-element-price">23&euro;</span>
</a>
<a href="/option2" class="top-element ">
    <div class="top-element-description">
        <div class="top-element-option-title">Greece</div>
        <div class="top-element-option-description">Test2</div>
    </div>
        <span class="top-element-price">25&euro;</span>
</a>
<a href="/option3" class="top-element ">
    <div class="top-element-description">
        <div class="top-element-option-title">Germany</div>
        <div class="top-element-option-description">Test3</div>
    </div>
        <span class="top-element-price">26&euro;</span>
</a>
<a href="/option4" class="top-element ">
    <div class="top-element-description">
        <div class="top-element-option-title">Austria</div>
        <div class="top-element-option-description">Test4</div>
    </div>
        <span class="top-element-price">29&euro;</span>
</a>
```

How do I make the selector so that I get:

1. Spain, Test1
2. Greece, Test2
3. Germany, Test3
4. Austria, Test4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a child selector?

```
a > div
```

If I test in [Jsoup online](https://try.jsoup.org/)

With your input I get:

```
Spain Test1
Greece Test2
Germany Test3
Austria Test4
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It seems that this has resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsop as below :

```
    String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.txt")));

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements elements = doc.body().getElementsByClass("top-element-description");

    for (Element el : elements) {
        System.out.println(el.text());
    }
```

Output is :

```
Spain Test1
Greece Test2
Germany Test3
Austria Test4
```